# Input string was not recognised as a valid datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
dataRow["BookDate"] = DateTime.ParseExact(date.ToString(), @"d/M/yyyy", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

my code is running locally but not on iis online 
the code is also ok with using online services as well.
also added in my web.config

Comment: what is your date format?

Comment: Show the value of date.

Comment: Why even use parse exact? Use normal try parse and from the resulting datetime save the .Date property into your datarow.

Comment: Let me understand, you have a DateTime variable called date, and you want it formatted as d/M/yyyy? Why then you convert it to a string, parse as a date and reconvert to a string?

Comment: i have taken varchar for bookdate in DB and entity

Comment: here date is of string type

Comment: And that's the root of your problem. In database, a Date should be stored as a Date not as a string. If possible change it. Do not confuse the display of a datetime value with its value. How do you plan to write a query that requires a range of date when the date is stored as a string?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for this formatted string. Your string can be represented as standart date and time format. You can use just [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Here an example on [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/);

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("05/04/2014 0:38",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
date.Dump();
```

If your `date` is already `DateTime`, you don't need to do anything. If you want to string representation of it, just use [`DateTime.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that takes `string` format and `IFormatProvider`.

```
date.ToString("d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that `date` is a DateTime variable, all you need is a simple ToString with a format specifier

```
  dataRow["BookDate"] = date.ToString("d/M/yyyy");
```

But this raises another question, is you `dataRow["BookDate"]` a string field?, If yes then you really shouldn't store date in string format. You use directly DateTime fields that are indipendent from the visual format and can be correctly used when you need to apply WHERE conditions in your database queries.

Instead, if `dataRow["BookDate"]` is correctly a DateTime field, then you don't need any kind of formatting, you assign directly a DateTime value to this field. It is the job of the code that display that value to format it accordingly to you preferences.

Comment: Hi Steve, just a tip; Would be better if you use `IFormatProvider` as a second parameter in my opinion because if OP's current culture `DateSeperator` is not `/`, the result will be different format than `d/M/yyyy`

Comment: Yes probably you have point here, but my biggest concern was about that conversion to/from datetime that seems totally unnecessary and wrong (if this is just a 'how to store a datatime value' problem)

Answer (score 0):

From Your comments if your Date Format is `05/04/2014 0:38`

**1** you need to use `dd` instead of `d` to represent two digit date.
**2** you need to use `MM` instead of `M` for representing the two digit Month.
**3** You need to use `H` for representing the Hour Format.
**4** You need to use `mm` for representing the minutes Format.

Try This:

```
dataRow["BookDate"] = DateTime.ParseExact(date.ToString(), @"dd/MM/yyyy H:mm", 
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

If you want to store only Date only.

Try This:

```
dataRow["BookDate"] = DateTime.ParseExact(date.ToString(), @"dd/MM/yyyy H:mm", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```